# How to use ng-model, in a modal. angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I have the following modal, With ng-model item

```
<div class="uk-modal" id="modal_header_footer">
<div class="uk-modal-dialog">
    <div class="uk-modal-header">
        <h3 class="uk-modal-title">Editar Usuario</h3>
    </div>
    <form id="form_validation" class="uk-form-stacked">
        <div class="uk-grid" data-uk-grid-margin>
            <div class="uk-width-medium-1-2">
                <div class="parsley-row">
                    <label for="fullname">user<span class="req">*</span></label>
                    <input type="text" ng-model="item.user" required class="md-input" md-input />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="uk-width-medium-1-2">
                   <div class="parsley-row">
                    <label for="fullname">name<span class="req">*</span></label>
                    <input id="nombre" type="text" name="nombre" ng-model="item.name" required class="md-input" md-input />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="uk-grid" data-uk-grid-margin>
            <div class="uk-width-medium-1-2">                     
                <div class="parsley-row">
                    <label for="email">Email<span class="req">*</span></label>
                    <input id="email" type="email" name="email" ng-model="item.email" data-parsley-trigger="change" required  class="md-input" md-input />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <div class="uk-modal-footer uk-text-right">
        <button type="button" class="md-btn md-btn-flat uk-modal-close">Cerrar</button>
        <button type="button" ng-click="EditarUsuario(item)" class="md-btn md-btn-flat md-btn-flat-primary">Aceptar</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

The modal call it from a button belonging to a record in datatable, "data-uk-modal="{target:\'#modal_header_footer\'}""

```
vm.dtColumns = [
              DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('id').withTitle('Id'),
              DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('usuario').withTitle('Usuario'),
              DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('nombre').withTitle('Nombre'),
              DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('email').withTitle('Email'),
              DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('telefono').withTitle('Telefono'),
              DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('estado').withTitle('Estado'),
              DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('created_at').withTitle('Creado'),
              DTColumnBuilder.newColumn(null).withClass('parent').withTitle('Acciones').notSortable().renderWith(function(data,type,full){
                  vm.usuario[data.id] = data; 
                    return   ' <a href="#" data-uk-modal="{target:\'#modal_header_footer\'}" ng-click="showCase.edit(showCase.usuario[' + data.id + '])"><i class="md-icon material-icons md-bg-light-blue-900 uk-text-contrast"></i></a>'+
                                ' <a href="#" data-uk-modal="{target:\'#modal_header_footer_eliminar\'}"><i class="md-icon material-icons md-bg-red-900 uk-text-contrast">&#xE872;</i></a>';
              })                    
          ];
```

I need to pass the data parameter, and so make use of the ng-model in the modal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference between the way we use [ng-model](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) in a modal and any other part of the website.

In your case, I suppose you want to show the user's data displayed which belong to a specific record in the table.

So if your `ng-model` in the modal belongs to the same controller which contains the `edit` func, you just need to bind the information passed as parameter to the corresponding `ng-model` in the modal. When the modal shows up, it will show the bind information in the modal.

Let's say, in your **modal** you have this:

```
<div class="parsley-row">
    <label for="fullname">user<span class="req">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="item.user" required class="md-input" md-input />
</div>
```

Then in your **edit** function you just have to say

```
function edit(user){
   $scope.item = user; //...item is the var used for binding the information to the modal and user is the var coming from the table
}
```

Comment: You're welcome! If this was useful to you, please [upvote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139/why-should-i-upvote-a-question) this question for future readers.

Comment: I still do not understand because when I make the change in the modal in the table There is no reflection so in real time, it is only until when I upload the page and I notice that I have updated the registry.

Comment: @JG_GJ, I'm sorry, I don't understand this last comment of yours. If you could describe how this flow goes it could be nice (and maybe, even, posting another question with this situation). There are a lot of people who can help here on SO. How are you doing the changes in the modal? Are you using just AngularJS, or is there anything else involved here. If you describe the situation better it would be nice in order to help you.

Answer (score 0):

This can solved using dummy object. here is a code

```
<td title="'Payment'"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg pay-btn"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" ng-click="mommy(obj)" >yuty</button>

  <!-- Modal content-->
  <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
```

```
<!-- Modal content-->
<div class="modal-content">

    <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
<div class="form-group">
<label>Amout</label>
<input type="Number" ng-model="vvv.payment">

</div>
```

```
                  <div class="modal-footer">
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" ng-  click="mono=false">Close</button>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-    click="modify(vvv._id,vvv)">Submit</button>
        </div>
  </div>
```

> dummy object

```
$scope.mommy = function(h){
 console.log(h.payment);
 $scope.vvv = h;
  }
```

hope you get to understand it,
This is better way to use it